# Load API based drawable in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, drawable, composable

We all know that we can load a drawable formed using `<shape>` or `<layer>` tag as a background using view.setBackground(drawable) in our traditional Android System.

Is there a way we can set these drawables as a background to a composable in Compose?

I know we can set background to a composable using a shape or brush but how can we do for the below case? Can't we load a xml which is declared below(normally lot of industry projects use)in compose?

Say i have an xml drawable named cta_3d.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/purple_light" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="@color/purple" />
            <corners android:radius="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I want to set it to the background of the text composable

```
Text(
        text = "This is a text composable",
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(16.dp),
        fontSize = 24.sp,
        color = Color.Black
    )
```

Tried using paint but it gave error whose reason is written below
Does anyone know how can we do it? Is there a way to load these as painterResource only loads vector or image assests only.

Tried painterResource but it can load only vector and images.